# what is the meaning of the star on inverter gate?

Tags: inverter, logic-gates

there is an star sign on the inverter gate in my homework circuit.
what is the meaning of it?
what is the difference between it and a normal one?
[image: the circuit schematic]

Comment: It means you need to look at the footnote. There's no standard meaning for such a star.

Comment: Take a look at a similar usage here: http://www.see.ed.ac.uk/~gerard/VLSI/Double.html

Comment: Same as in English. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Note_%28typography%29  just this is marking a specific component for discussion, not a specific component marking

Answer (score 1):

It looks (based on the link here: http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/printpage/Introduction-to-Logic-Gates/237) like the * means it's an open-collector inverter. "Open collector means that the transistor used on the output of the gate doesn't have its collector internally connected to the integrated circuit's VCC (voltage). So, you have to do this connection by yourself. This means that you need to install an external resistor (called “pull-up”) between the output and VCC to make the circuit work. The good thing is that VCC doesn’t need to be the +5 V power supply. You can install it to a + 12 V power supply and feed your 12 V relay, for example.... open drain is used for CMOS.... Open collector or open drain circuits are usually marked with an asterisk."

Here's an open-drain buffer with a similar (but not identical) symbol:
[image: an open-drain buffer with a similar symbol]
<sub>(source: [maximintegrated.com](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/images/appnotes/214/1189Fig02b.gif))</sub>

Comment: Note that the standard symbol is [⎐](http://codepoints.net/U+2390). A line across the gate near the output may also be acceptable.

Comment: Ignacio answered as I was finding the image - thanks!